# Thousands separator formatter for an entry in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I  am working on a **Page** where I have several **Entries** to enter numerical values ​​(integers and with decimal point).

The requirement is that each field formats the value with decimal point and thousands separators (eg: 1.254.356,42).

The following code formats the value correctly. The problem is that the cursor does jumps to the end always when the text changes:

```
private void TbLenght_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var textbox = (Entry)sender;
    var tempValue = double.Parse(textbox.Text, culture);
    var newFormat = tempValue.ToString("N2", culture);
    textbox.Text = newFormat;
}
```

Which options do I have to achieve my goal?

Comment: I think a mask is what you are looking for. Take a look, for instance here:
https://xamarinhelp.com/masked-entry-in-xamarin-forms/

Comment: Enable the Numeric Keyboard for that Entry which requires the number only values so that user can enter only number!
For the format you should probably start looking on how to mask entry field.

Comment: If you need to set the cursor position then you can do "textbox.CursorPosition = 4;"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The following code formats the value correctly. The problem is that the cursor does jumps to the end always when the text changes:

You can change current CursorPosition for entry to make current CursorPosition before the decimal point, please take a look the following code:

```
        var textbox = (Entry)sender;
        var tempValue = double.Parse(textbox.Text, culture);
        var newFormat = tempValue.ToString("N2", culture);
        textbox.Text = newFormat;
        textbox.CursorPosition = newFormat.Length-3;
```